# PyMySQL: Query with large number of rows failing

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a very simple query I'm executing with PyMySQL:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `records` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

`records` has over 1.5 million rows in it. `id` is a primary key.

Is this a limitation of PyMySQL? Is there something else I should be using if I'm querying so many rows at once?

Comment: It's throwing an exception after ~2 minutes saying that the connection failed.

Comment: Note that it still works fine with smaller queries (say, 500k rows). So it's something to do with the 1.5 million rows.

Comment: I think nathans answer below is probably the most correct ... are you querying against localhost? or to a remote server? they may have timeouts for persistent connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break the query into several smaler queries:

```
from math import ceil

batch_size = 1000

for start_at in range(int(ceil(total_rows / 1000 * 1.0))):
    sql = 'SELECT `id` from `RECORDS` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT %i, %i'
    sql = sql % (start_at * batch_size, batch_size)
    # fetch rows
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've resorted to currently. Is there a less-hacky way to do it though? Surely there's a way to do it with a single query?

Comment: It could be that the database is killing any query that is open for more than 2 minutes. If this is the case then you will have to modify your MySQL config. I would see what happens with a different mysql package such as mysql-python. You could also try using cursors.

Comment: Interesting, when I enter "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';" in MySQL, it gives 7800, which is at least a couple hours...

Comment: Check all the timeout variables, with `LIKE '%timeout%'`. What is the [net_write_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_write_timeout) value?